# issue with aligning items in center of a View component

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox, styled-components

I am using react native and `styled-components` and trying to center content in the middle of a `View` component.

My code looks like the following:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FixturesContainer>
          {fixtures.map((fixture, i) => {
            return (
              <View key={fixture.fixture}>             
                <FixtureTextContainer>
                  <TeamText>{fixtureText[0]}</TeamText>
                  <FixtureText>{fixture.kickOffTime}</FixtureText>
                  <TeamText>{fixtureText[1]}</TeamText>
                </FixtureTextContainer>
              </View>
            )
          })}
        </FixturesContainer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const FixtureTextContainer = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
`

const FixtureText = styled.Text`
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
`

const TeamText = styled.Text`
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
`
```

It looks like the below. You can see that the names and the time is not aligned. I have tried all the different combinations of `text-align: center` and `justify-content` but I cannot centralize these. Can anyone advise?

[image]

Comment: well why would they be aligned? the container is justify-content:center. but they are each have different lengths, and different spaces between the words. dont forget that the center is for the entire row... not per element. so thats how it looks. if you want to make sure that they all fit in boxes. the only idea I have is to define the sizes so the center will always be the same. or maybe try defining a box for the container and set them as space-between.

Comment: something like this maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/gmbqLk5c/13/

Comment: @Jony-Y I know this is the expected behavior, but was looking for a a different approach, which you provided, thanks. What you provided looks good, thanks!